# phpize command not found

Tags: centos5, command, memcache

I was installing memcache on my Cent OS 5 server and I am following this guide > http://www.howtoforge.com/php_memcache_centos5.0

And now, when I enter,
`phpize && ./configure --enable-memcache && make`

the server says `phpize: command not found`

So, I tried this command `yum -y install php-devel` and following is the answer from the server

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Repository 'vz-base' is missing name in configuration, using id
Repository 'vz-updates' is missing name in configuration, using id
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * addons: mirror.5ninesolutions.com
 * base: mirror.san.fastserv.com
 * extras: mirror.nwresd.org
 * rpmforge: apt.sw.be
 * updates: mirror.5ninesolutions.com
Excluding Packages in global exclude list
Finished
Setting up Install Process
No package php-devel available.
Nothing to do
```

So... any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where did you install php-devel to? The default directory? It seems that phpize either isn't installed or itsn't not in your path. Can you run a find for phpize? Once located, you can either add this to you path, or call it directly.

Comment: type whereis phpize and it should locate it. Then execute it from the full path. let's say /usr/bin/phpize for the sake of this example.

Comment: I used this `/usr/local/bin/phpize && ./configure --enable-memcache --with-php-config=/usr/local/bin/php-config && make` and it has been installed well. Thanks for both of you :D

Answer (score 2):

Add [jasonlitka repository](http://www.jasonlitka.com/yum-repository/)

Install php-devel:

```
yum -y install php-devel
```

Comment: I've just updated the question with the result...

Comment: still no any success :(